# Go through every Folder with GetDirectory

Tags: c#, file, recursion, directory

Here is my code:

```
private static bool checkifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(string path, string fileExestention) //Like C:\\smth, *.html
    {          
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path,fileExestention))
            {
                return true;
            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                 return checkifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(d,fileExestention);
            }
            return false;
    }
```

In this function the program returns every file with specified extention BUT If I contain only one file with the specified extention in the last folder, the function returns false, which makes no sence because it exists

My question is why it does that...

Try it out. I can't really find the bug.

Comment: Can you show **how you called** such function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "return" inside the foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) loop.  It will only check the first directory per level.  You need something like this (not nice, but keeping your style/format)

```
bool ok = false;
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    ok = ok || checkifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(d,
       fileExestention);
}
return ok;
```

Better yet, use the linq that Marc provided.

Answer (score 0):

Turned this into a LINQ query

```
    private static bool CheckifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(string path, string fileExestention)
        //Like C:\\smth, *.html
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(path, fileExestention).Any() ||
               Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                        .Select(d => CheckifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(d, fileExestention))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Tried it on the a few debug folders using *.exe as the mask and it returns true. It traverses sub folders as well. Not sure what you meant by one file in the last folder.

See if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflowSnippets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = @"C:\smth"; String pattern = "*.html";

            Console.WriteLine("__" + checkifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(path, pattern));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool checkifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(string path, string fileExestention) //Like C:\\smth, *.html
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path, fileExestention))
            {
                return true;
            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                if (checkifDirectoryContainsFilesWithSpecifiedExtention(Path.Combine(path, d), fileExestention))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```